# Apache: RewriteRule removing trailing dot

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, trailing

Here is my .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1&item=$2&var2=%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1 [NC]
```

Here is an url (with trailing dot in the end):
`http://localhost/test/secondvar.`

The problem is that the trailing dot is not coming inside the `var2` `GET` variable

I used a `print_r($_GET)` and here is the result with the above url:

```
Array ( [var1] => test [var2] => secondvar [uri] => /test/secondvar. )
```

So my question is, how do I get that trailing dot from the URL as a parameter to the var? As you can see, the `REQUEST_URI` is showing that the apache knows of the dot.

I know I can not send the paths as `GET` parameters and take care to read the paths in the URI from PHP, but I would like to know why the dot isn't coming and how to fix it, if too complicated I rather go for the direct PHP solution.

EDIT: Is not only trailing dot but trailing ? too... =[

Comment: You're not going to be able to easily get the trailing ? because it's not part of the `{REQUEST_URI}`, it's interpreted as a delimiter between your request uri and the query string.

I quickly tried to recreate the problem and I can't. Trailing . works like a charm.

What version of php and apache are you you using?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.0,
Apache 2.0 Handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might just be that php excludes trailing dots. I know that they often convert dot's in POST/GET to underscores. I would just do

```
explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```